# Keyup event not registered after contextmenu event

Tags: javascript, jquery, contextmenu, keydown, keyup

I am trying out this following code. It is supposed to change the `sh` attribute of the input to 1 whenever the `shift` key is pressed, and revert back to 0 when released

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
 $(document).on("keyup","body",function(e) {
   if (e.which == 16) {
     $("input").attr("sh","0");
   }
 });

$(document).on("keydown","body",function(e) {
  if (e.which == 16) {
     $("input").attr("sh","1");
   }
 });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type = 'text' sh = '0'/>
<p>Just checking</p>
</body>
</html>
```

It works fine, except when this sequence of events is executed. Press the shift key while the input is not in focus. (Firebug shows `sh` becoming 1, as expected). Now with the key still pressed, focus in on the input. Now do a right click on the input. The context menu pops up. Now if you release the `shift` key (let the contextmenu remain), Firebug shows that `sh` is still 1. You click outside the contextmenu to make it go, or even click the `paste` option to paste your clipboard text in the input, still `sh` remains 1. If you again press and release `shift`, only then `sh` becomes 0 again.

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Do you have to check for the 'shift' key on all the 'document' or on the input is enough??

Comment: instead of "body" try "*". Hope this will help.

Comment: @KundanSinghChouhan, no luck mate, it still remains 1 if I use `*`!

Comment: @ebramtharwat, no I need to check the whole document..

Answer (score 0):

Does the following help you? 
I am not sure I simulated your scenario correctly, but seems to work for me. I tested in Chrome.

$(document).ready(function () {

```
$(document).keyup(function (e) {
    if (e.which == 16) {
        $("input").attr("sh", "0");
        console.log($("input").attr("sh"));
    }
});

$(document).keydown(function (e) {
    if (e.which == 16) {
        $("input").attr("sh", "1");
        console.log($("input").attr("sh"));
    }
});

//Works... (holding shift will raise keydown as much as I hold the key...)
//$(document).keyup(function (e) {
//    if (e.keyCode == 16) {
//        console.log("Shift was released...");
//    }
//});

//$(document).keydown(function (e) {
//    if (e.keyCode == 16) {
//        console.log("Shift was pressed down...");
//    }
//});
```

});